# How to stop ratpack run under netbeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, gradle, task, ratpack

**Problem:**

After starting ratpack application under netbeans IDE there's no way to stop it.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Checkout project: https://github.com/akhikhl/ratpack-helloworld.git
2. Start netbeans 7.4 (Gradle Support IDE plugin must be installed)
3. Open project ratpack-helloworld
4. Invoke menu command "Run/Run Project" - gradle task starts nicely, app waits on port 5050.
5. Now try to stop it:

   - There's no task for stopping ratpack app
   - Ctrl+Break has no effect
   - menu command "Run/Stop Buid/Run..." has no effect
   - when clicking "Cancel Running Task button, IDE asks "Are you sure you want to cancel...", then it reports "Build failure", but run task is still running.

**Workaround**

Restarting IDE kind of solves the problem, but eliminates fun factor from using ratpack.

**Question**

Any ideas on how to stop ratpack under netbeans the legitimate way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [X] button in the bottom bar to cancel the gradle run task.[image: Gradle-netbeans]